# Interface Builder issue with Tab Bar

Tags: ios, xcode, interface-builder, tabbar, uitabbaritem

I have duplicated this on both Xcode 6 - beta 2 AND Xcode 5 on a different machine. Surely this can't be a bug as it is such a common task it would have been caught by now.

I drag a tab bar to a view controller. All good.

I drag an additional tab bar item to the tab bar. Not good. The tab bar becomes obscured by a grey box. The grey box stays visible when the app is built and run.

Has this happened to any of you? Any ideas?

Short screen recording to demonstrate: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=r-iS-tmUmBM&feature=youtu.be!

Pictures:

[BEFORE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kqFs5.png)

[AFTER](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OoaKf.png)

Comment: What version of OSX are you using?

Comment: I tried it on both Xcode 6 - beta 2 running on Yosemite and Xcode 5 running on Mavericks. Same results.

Comment: I hit the same issue, at the same time as you. Did you find a solution elsewhere?

Comment: No I didn't. It went on for 2 days and then stopped happening. So.. I'd say give it a couple days lol

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this issue on Xcode 5.1.1 on OS X 10.9.4.
Was an annoying little bug and I hope this helps someone.

I was able to fix it by setting the image for each UITabBarItem.

Answer (score 0):

This "bug" or whatever is causing this behavior only occurs if you have set the `Tab Bar Item` to custom and have no image set. It is automatically custom when you add a new one.

The other `Tab Bar Items` that are added with the predefined Tab Bar are
[standard items](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kqFs5.png)

If you set the image of the custom `Tab Bar Item` it will have the normal appearance again.
I ran in the same problem with the `Tab Bar Controller`

I've no idea why this is happening I just hope it will magically disappear tomorrow...